# How do I get past ColdFusion server-specific error code 2?

Tags: coldfusion, adobe

I had installed ColdFusion 2018 recently and with the installation less than a month old (and my understanding of the technology even less), my Cold Fusion service has stopped working. I have tried a number of things and have referred to a number of articles and out of many such errors where the service is not being accessible, some of them were able to get it resolved. However, some other obscure reason that may be causing this error have been untouched and unknown.

Whenever, I try to restart the service, I get an error as shown below:

> Windows could not start the ColdFusion 8 Application Server on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to server-specific code error 2.”

Without much understanding, I started to google it out. Looking into every one of these posts, I tried

1. Configure JRE and try to relaunch the service by looking at "JAVA_HOME" variable and JVM.config
2. Run the batch files in every possible combination to find if anything clicks
3. Check if the present JAVA version works and is compatible with Coldfusion version installed
4. Fiddling with the "SessionStorage" var in neo-runtime.xml file as some suggested

and few other tricks coupled with a numerous service restart attempts and a few machine reboots as well.

A service that renders Cold Fusion pages should be shut down abruptly. To add to agony, the CF Admin also depends on the service and hence does not work.

Any pointers to any potential solutions?

Comment: What do you see in ColdFusion's error logs?

Comment: Are you sure you are not running multiple instances of coldfusion on your computer? 'ColdFusion 8 Application' is more then a decade old and not the same as coldfusion 2018. Maybe a complete deinstallation and then reinstallation is the quickest solution.

Comment: 1. Start by finding more details about the error message. What do the System Event log AND the CF8 exception logs say? 2. What java version did you use in jvm.config? Is it 32 or 64 bit? CF8 is very old and won't be compatible with the newer versions used by CF2018. Also, did you verify the java path is correct?

Comment: The cause of the issue is apparent: you have installed ColdFusion 2018 on top of an existing ColdFusion 8 installation. To resolve the issue, proceed as follows: (1) Uninstall ColdFusion 8 (backing files up where necessary). (2) Uninstall ColdFusion 2018. (3) Restart Windows. (4) Install ColdFusion 2018 as before.

Comment: Guys, I have not installed any ColdFusion version earlier ever. I am giving it a try by reinstalling CF again. Actually, I was not expecting a very quick response and/or resolution with regards to this query. And also, in the meanwhile, our team should be getting a new machine for setting up another installation of CF. Which is why I am resorting to a solution that worked for some of the posts here...

Comment: Perhaps it is a typo, but this part suggests otherwise "I get an error as shown below .. Windows could not start the **ColdFusion 8** Application Server".  In any event, the answers to some of the earlier questions might help shed some light on the issue.